# Exception when maps java.math.BigDecimal to DB2 Numeric data type

Tags: java, sql, db2, hibernate-mapping, numeric

In the work we use a DB2 database and in one table the primary key is of type Numeric. For that table I make an entity class and I set a BigDecimal property for the primary key. When try to insert a new row in that table using

```
entityManager.persist(entity);
```

everything is OK. The new row is added to the table. But the problem is in that we need to insert multiple records at once and for that reason I implemented this method:

```
public void addCars(final List<CarContainer> cars) throws SQLException {

    Date date = new Date();
    final java.sql.Date recDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
    final Timestamp dateCreated = new Timestamp(date.getTime());

    Session session = em.unwarp(Session.class);

    session.doWork(new Work() {

        @Override
        public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
String carsSql = "INSERT INTO " + 
                    "cars" +
                    "   (cars_id, cars_name,   
cars_rec_status, created)" +
                    "VALUES" +
                    "   (?, ?, ?, ?)";

            NullablePreparedStatement carsPreparedStatement =   
NullablePreparedStatement.wrap(connection.prepareStatement(carsSql));

            for (CarContainer carContainer : cars) {

                brandsPreparedStatement
                .setBigDecimal(1, carContainer.getCarId())
                .setString(2, carContainer.getName())
                .setShort(3, carContainer.getRecordStatus())
                .setDate(4, recDate,   
 DateUtil.getCalendarInstance());

                carsPreparedStatement.unwrap().addBatch();
        }

 carsPreparedStatement.unwrap().executeBatch();

            if (!carsPreparedStatement.unwrap().isClosed()) {
                carsPreparedStatement.unwrap().close();
            }
    });
}
```

And in that is the problem. When I use native query I'm getting exception when on that line of code:

```
 .setBigDecimal(1, carContainer.getBrandsId())
```

For some reason BigDecimal is not mapped correctly to numeric when native insert is used.

Comment: And the exception is...?

Comment: The exception is "java.sql.SQLException: Connection is not associated with a managed connection.org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6@65cdfb"

Comment: I don't see how "Connection is not associated..." is related to the data type mapping. Do you get any DB2 SQLCODE value?

Comment: The SQL error that I get is: SqL error 0, Sql State null

Comment: Actually I also don't see how this exception is related with dats type mapping, but the fact is that the exception is thrown when the first parameter is set.

Comment: Wait, I just noticed this - why is the date attribute being set to index `5`?  You only have four replacement variables.  Beyond that... what other things have you tried?  Can you give it an integer (and set it as such)?  Can we get the table creation script?  Why is your id a numeric anyways - most people use an integer.  And are you sure there's no collision with an existing id (which should be a different exception, but still)?

Comment: I'm typed a wrong index while as writing the post. I tried to pass hardcoded value for id in the query but then the same exception is thrown for the second parameter - .setString(1, carContainer.getName()). And before you ask - yes I fixed the indexes before running the method.

Comment: You instantiate `carsPreparedStatement`, then use `setBigDecimal()` on some `brandsPreparedStatement`. Quit drinking vodka!

Answer (score 0):

@mustaccio thanks for the tip, but no need for. I don't drink vodka or anything else ;). My problem was solved and the problem was in the method carContainer.getCarId() which make select query. I didn't know that in doWork method I shouldn't make select query. After select EntityManager is closing the connection and that cause the exception.